# PHP - Get Meta Information by EmbedURL

Tags: metadata, php-7

How I will get meta information specified by EmbedURL? I have tried `get_meta_tags('raw_html')`. But it returns nothing.

**MY HTML:**

```
<!--Video 1-->
        <div class="embed-responsive-item" itemprop="video" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
                                      <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls="" loop="">
                            <source src="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL">
                          </video>
                         <meta itemprop="name" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="duration" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="THUMBNAIL_URL">
                         <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL">
                          <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z">
            </div>
<!--Video 2-->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" onclick="loadYoutubeVideoThroughYTApi(this)" data-src-id="player-1" data-yut-var="YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID">
                <meta itemprop="description" content="META_DESCRIPTION_2">
                <meta itemprop="duration" content="PT1M13S">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="META_TITLE_2">
                <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg">
               <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID">
              <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2019-02-04T11:00:43.000Z">
            </div>
<!--Video 3-->
    <div class="embed-responsive-item" itemprop="video" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
                                      <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls="" loop="">
                            <source src="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL_2">
                          </video>
                         <meta itemprop="name" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="duration" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="THUMBNAIL_URL_2">
                         <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL_2">
                          <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z">
            </div>
```

As you can see the html contains three different videos with three different meta properties. So the result array should be look like this

**Desired Output:**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [url] => INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL
                [meta_name] => NULL
                [meta_description] => NULL // as you can see no meta tags for description
                [meta_duration] => NULL
                [meta_thumbnail] => THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_URL
                [upload_date] => 2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID
                [meta_name] => META_TITLE_2
                [meta_description] => META_DESCRIPTION_2
                [meta_duration] => PT1M13S
                [meta_thumbnail] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg
                [upload_date] => 2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [url] => INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL_2
                [meta_name] => NULL
                [meta_description] => NULL // as you can see no meta tags for description
                [meta_duration] => NULL
                [meta_thumbnail] => THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_URL_2
                [upload_date] => 2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z
            )
    )
```

How will I get the set of array like this?

Comment: Why not use regex?

Comment: How will I achieve this? Please share a solution..